# SimpleCursorAdaptor NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, listadapter

I tried to implement the adapter mentioned above with the help of the tutorials provided by android but the app crashes as soon as i launch the activity with the error of NoClassDefFound

here is the Log of the error.

```
01-07 13:56:32.322: W/dalvikvm(9379): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419be700)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at com.assassin.expensemanager.HistoryActivity.onCreate(HistoryActivity.java:43)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5204)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
01-07 13:56:32.342: E/AndroidRuntime(9379):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 13:56:33.764: I/Process(9379): Sending signal. PID: 9379 SIG: 9
```

Also here is the code that i used

```
package com.assassin.expensemanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HistoryActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtHistory;
    private ListView lvHistoryDetails;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        // Initializing Views
        txtHistory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHistory);
        lvHistoryDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvHistoryDetails);

        // Initializing DBs and cursors
        SQLiteDatabase expenses = MainActivity.expensesDb.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "Select * from " + ExpenseDBHelper.tableName;
        Cursor cursor = expenses.rawQuery(sql, null);



        // Setting Views
        try {

            String [] fromColumns = new String[4];
            fromColumns = ExpenseDBHelper.columns;
            int [] toViews = {R.id.txtHistoryDate, R.id.txtHistoryCategory, R.id.txtHistoryDescription, R.id.txtHistoryAmount};

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.history_row, cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0) ;
            lvHistoryDetails.setAdapter(adapter);


/*          StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder("");
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String date = cursor.getString(1);
                String category = cursor.getString(2);
                String desc = cursor.getString(3);
                double amount = cursor.getDouble(4);
                txt.append( id + " " + date + " " + category + " " + desc + " "
                        + amount + "\n");
                txtHistory.setText(txt);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.d("HistoryActivity", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try going to **Project** -> **Properties** -> **Java Build Path** -> **Order & Export** and ensure `Android Private Libraries` are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;`
with `import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;`

It should work

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why?

Answer (score 0):

just go to your project properties then java build path and add your android.jar file. Check it that it is check marked or not?

Solve your problem  and enjoy.